# How can I extract top 5 sums?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

```
=QUERY('BD3'!A:Q,
"SELECT L,D,I,SUM(M)
WHERE I='W34' AND M>0 AND L='Huacho' 
GROUP BY L,D,I",-1)
```

I need to just show the top 5 sums of column M.

Comment: If this works anything like MySQL or Presto then `ORDER BY` and then `LIMIT 5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=query('BD3'!A:Q, "SELECT L,D,I, SUM(M) WHERE I='W34' AND M>0 and L='Huacho' GROUP BY L,D,I ORDER BY SUM(M) DESC LIMIT 5",-1)
```